# Creating following pdf in C# with itextsharp?

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to make a pdf in C# with itextsharp that should look something like this image. Im just having trouble finding a good manual for using itextsharp and I cant for example get the headline to get placed to the right of the logo. It just wants to go down to the next line. Im really thankful for all help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSaVG.png

Comment: Can you post the code that you've tried?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KwLj3qxZ Here is the code I've written. What is the best way to place the text that comes after the logotype and the heading?

Comment: You can find a good manual on the official website: http://developers.itextpdf.com

Answer (score 0):

Probably the way to go is with absolute position. 
For example:

```
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(<pdfcontentbyte>);
ct.setSimpleColumn("Headline",<lower_left_x_corner>,<lower_left_y_corner>,
<upper_right_x_corner>,<upper_right_y_corner>,<leading>,<alignment>);
ct.Go();
```

you can also look up to the setTextMatrix or showTextAligned methods.

Just remember that the coordinates start at the bottom left corner of the page.

Comment: I've tried your code and the only thing that goes beneath the logo is the "LAX" line. The other one stands to the right of the logo.

Answer (score -1):

```
    private void ExportToPdfDemo()
    {

        try
        {

            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            // string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + @"\PURCHASE REPORTS\";
            string appPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + @"\Sales Report\";
            if (Directory.Exists(appPath) == false)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(appPath);
            }
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(appPath + "/" + txt_ReferenceNo.Text + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
            document.Open();
            PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
            cb.SetLineWidth(2.0f);   // Make a bit thicker than 1.0 default
            cb.SetGrayStroke(0.95f); // 1 = black, 0 = white
            cb.MoveTo(20, document.Top - 30f);
            cb.LineTo(400, document.Top - 30f);
            cb.Stroke();

            PdfPTable Ttable = new PdfPTable(1);
            float[] widths = new float[] { 1f };
            Ttable.SetWidths(widths);


            PdfPCell numeroCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Reference No: " + txt_ReferenceNo.Text));
            numeroCell.Border = 0;
            numeroCell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            Ttable.AddCell(numeroCell);


            numeroCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Date: " + dtpPurchaseDate.Text));
            numeroCell.Border = 0;
            numeroCell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            Ttable.AddCell(numeroCell);

            numeroCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Customer Code: " + txt_CustomerCode.Text));
            numeroCell.Border = 0;
            numeroCell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            Ttable.AddCell(numeroCell);



            numeroCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Customer Name: " + txt_CustomerName.Text));
            numeroCell.Border = 0;
            numeroCell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            Ttable.AddCell(numeroCell);




            numeroCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(""));
            numeroCell.Border = 0;
            numeroCell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            Ttable.AddCell(numeroCell);


            numeroCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(""));
            numeroCell.Border = 0;
            numeroCell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            Ttable.AddCell(numeroCell);




            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);
            widths = new float[] { 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f };
            table.SetWidths(widths);
            numeroCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Product Code"));
            numeroCell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(1, 159, 222);
            numeroCell.Border = 0;
            numeroCell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            table.AddCell(numeroCell);

            numeroCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Product Name"));
            numeroCell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(1, 159, 222);
            numeroCell.Border = 0;
            numeroCell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            table.AddCell(numeroCell);


            numeroCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Unit Price"));
            numeroCell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(1, 159, 222);
            numeroCell.Border = 0;
            numeroCell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            table.AddCell(numeroCell);


            numeroCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Quantity"));
            numeroCell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(1, 159, 222);
            numeroCell.Border = 0;
            numeroCell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            table.AddCell(numeroCell);



            numeroCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Total Price"));
            numeroCell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(1, 159, 222);
            numeroCell.Border = 0;
            numeroCell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            table.AddCell(numeroCell);

            PdfPCell cell;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grd_PurchaseList.Rows)
            {

                cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(row.Cells["PurchseProductCode"].Value.ToString()));
                cell.Border = 0;
                cell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                table.AddCell(cell);

                cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(row.Cells["PurchasePName"].Value.ToString()));
                cell.Border = 0;
                cell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                table.AddCell(cell);

                cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(row.Cells["PurchaseQuantity"].Value.ToString()));
                cell.Border = 0;
                cell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                table.AddCell(cell);

                cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(row.Cells["PurchaseUnitPrice"].Value.ToString()));
                cell.Border = 0;
                cell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                table.AddCell(cell);


                cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(row.Cells["PurchaseTotalPrice"].Value.ToString()));
                cell.Border = 0;
                cell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                table.AddCell(cell);

            }


            for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++)
            {
                cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(""));
                cell.Border = 0;
                cell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                table.AddCell(cell);
            }

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Tax Amount :"));
            cell.Border = 0;
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            table.AddCell(cell);

            double taxAmount = Convert.ToDouble(txt_GrandTotal.Text) - Convert.ToDouble(txt_SubTotal.Text);


            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("" + taxAmount));
            cell.Border = 0;
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            table.AddCell(cell);



            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(""));
                cell.Border = 0;
                cell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
                table.AddCell(cell);
            }


            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Total Amount :"));
            cell.Border = 0;
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            table.AddCell(cell);


            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(txt_GrandTotal.Text));
            cell.Border = 0;
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            table.AddCell(cell);


            //table.SpacingBefore = 20f;
            //table.SpacingAfter = 30f;

            document.Add(Ttable);
            Ttable.SpacingAfter = 40f;
            document.Add(table);
            document.Close();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you *explain* your code? There's a lot of it - somebody else seeing that won't find it as useful as you might want.